# AllowHttpStatus still throw Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException

Tags: c#, flurl

I am using `AllowHttpStatus` to disable exception throwing on HTTP errors and to handle exceptions by myself. Unfortunately, I still get an exception.

> Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException. Call failed with status code 500
>   (Internal Server Error): POST http://MyUrl  Request

The code

```
var request = new Url("http://MyUrl").AllowHttpStatus();

var content = new FileContent(Conversion.SourceFile.FileInfo.ToString());

var task = request.PostAsync(content, model.CancellationToken);
using (var httpStream = await task.ReceiveStream())
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(DestinationLocation + @"\result." + model.DestinationFileFormat, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

//This line is never reached if HTTP Exception is thrown by PostAsync   
if (task.Result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    if (task.Result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        Logger.Main.LogCritical($"Exception {task.Result.ReasonPhrase}");
    }

    throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.ConversionFailed);
}
```

Why is `AllowHttpStatus` not working as expected?

Comment: Furl apears to be not a .NET Library, so it propably ignores such an atribute. | As for how to handle it: HTTP errors tend to be in the Exogenous realm of this classification: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Christopher Flurl **is** a .NET library

Comment: @DavidG: I could not find it in the .NET or .NET core documentation. Only as a seperate thing on GitHub, Nuget and it's own page. At best it is a inofficial companion Library. | But it is good to know it does follow those Attributes. Or at least the code it (likely) wraps around does.

Comment: @Christopher So you meant to say it's not part of the core libraries, which you could say for 99% of the .NET ecosystem.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe we got a different definition of Core Libraries? This is what I call CoreLibraries/Part of .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/ | Furl has all the signs of being a 3rd Party Library for .NET. Same as very .exe and .dll I ever made. Wich is fully useable per the MSIL/CLR rules, but not a offcial thing. So it might miss some patterns/rules.

Comment: @Christopher But you didn't say "Core", that's the confusion here.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, Flurl is a 3rd party library, but I'm not sure how that's relevant to the question. When you say "it propably ignores such an atribute" and " it might miss some patterns/rules", I'm not sure what exactly are you're referring to, but the `AllowHttpStatus` method is defined in Flurl. It's not ignoring its own methods.

Comment: @ToddMenier I said: "Furl apears to be not a .NET Library, so it propably ignores such an atribute." | As it turns out from the accepted answer, it was just the Atribute being improperly used. | I said: "But it is good to know it does follow those Attributes. Or at least the code it (likely) wraps around does." Admitting I was wrong. | So what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowHttpStatus` takes parameters. Without them, it has no effect. So in this case you need to pass it `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` for example:

```
var request = new Url("http://MyUrl").AllowHttpStatus(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

Alternatively use `AllowAnyHttpStatus` instead:

```
var request = new Url("http://MyUrl").AllowAnyHttpStatus();
```